# HTML5 canvas to XML and vice versa

Tags: xml, html, canvas

Just started to using HTML5 canvas. I had drawn a diagram and I want to save the diagram as XML file not as image file. so that i can import it later. Is there any plug-ins available to do that. please advice how can i achieve canvas to XML.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what XML format you want to export the drawing to.

But my advice would be to do the drawing using SVG instead of Canvas. SVG is already an XML format, so you wouldn't need to do any converting to XML.

Comment: @rajaishbt - not easily. Canvas is basically a pixel-based free drawing area, so it's not an obvious candidate to be saved as XML. You'll find that vector graphics are much better for this, and as I say, the SVG format is already in XML format when it's in the browser, so no conversion necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that something like [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) might do what you require. This is a Javascript library that parses an SVG file and renders it to a `canvas` instance.

(I'm assuming SVG is what you want; that would be the logical choice).